# Monitor disk usage with MongoDB Ops Manager

Tags: mongodb, linux, disk-space, monitoring, mongodb-3.0

We use [MongoDB Ops Manager](https://www.mongodb.com/products/ops-manager) 1.6.2.251.

I searched Activity -> Alert Settings. Is there a way to monitor disk usage?

To get an alert if this changes to 90%:

```
# df -h /data/
Filesystem                Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vdatavg-data   99G  295M   99G   1% /data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB Ops Manager 3.4.0 (released November, 2016) includes monitoring for hardware metrics (cpu, disk usage, and I/O utilization) via the Automation agent. For more information, see: [System and Disk Alerts](https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/current/reference/alerts/#system-and-disk-alerts).

Prior versions of Ops Manager did not include hardware monitoring and required the use of an external tool (`munin-node`) for CPU & disk metrics. If you are still using an older version of Ops Manager and have installed [Munin-node](http://munin-monitoring.org/) for [monitoring CPU & I/O stats](https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/current/tutorial/configure-monitoring-munin-node/) you could look into using the Munin `df` plugin to track free disk space. Munin supports [sending alerts](http://munin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/alert.html) via email as well as through Nagios and external scripts.